# Making a dynamic array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, blogs

THE ANSWER THAT WORKED FOR ME BASED ON AN ANSWER GIVEN

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($tags)) {
        $push = explode(',', $post['tags']);
        $array = array_merge($array, $push);
}
```

So I'm trying to display tags from my data base and make links out of them like this:

```
<?
$tags = mysql_query( 'SELECT tags  FROM `Table`');
$array = array();
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($tags)) {
$push = explode(',', $post['tags']);
array_push($array, $push);
}
foreach ($array as $value) {?>
    <a href="url.php?tags=<? echo $value?>"><? echo $value?></a>
<? }
?>
```

However all I get back is

```
    <a href="url.php?tags=Array">Array</a>
```

Where I should be having at least three lines as was previously produced by

```
<?
$tags = mysql_query( 'SELECT tags  FROM `Table`');
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($tags)) {
$array = explode(',', $post['tags']);
foreach ($array as $value) {?>
<a href="url.php?tags=<? echo $value?>"><? echo $value?></a>
<? }
}
?>
```

The code being called looks like this:

```
tag1, tag2, tag3
```

Tried

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($tags)) {
    $push = explode(',', $post['tags']);
array_merge($array, $push);
}
foreach ($array as $value) {?>
<a href="index.php?tags=<? echo $value?>"><? echo $value?></a>
```

now foreach doesn't return a value

Comment: Just to point this out: try to use `<?php  ?>` syntax

Comment: why did you explode $post[tags]?

Comment: @tunmisefasipe probably because they're stored in the database as a comma-separated string.

Comment: I guessed so.Made it confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), because `array_push()` will push the output of `explode()`, which is an array, as a whole to the array in the first argument, creating a jagged array.

As for your edit, this works:

```
$array = array_merge($array, $push);

foreach ($array as $value)
{
    echo '<a href="url.php?tags=' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}
```

Please note that `array_merge()` (contrary to `array_push()`, gotta love the consistency) does not alter the array passed as its first argument, so you'll have to store the return value which I do on the first line (`$array = ...`).

While outputting to HTML, you also might want to put a `$value = htmlentities(trim($value));` in the `foreach` loop.